# Keep Getting null on DataRowView'

Tags: c#, datagrid

```
        private void OnDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        { 
            DataGrid dataGrid = (DataGrid)sender;
            DataRowView row_selected = dataGrid.SelectedItem as DataRowView;

            var s = row_selected["Nome"].ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(s);
        }
```

I'm trying to make a cell value message box when selected

Comment: You need to state the `DataGrid`'s namespace as in `System.Web.UI.WebControls` or `System.Windows.Controls`. If the latter are you sure you've selected a cell rather than the whole row (the row is the default)? If you've got a cell then try the `SelectedCells` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what exactly you want to achive but I assume that your trying to pop a message box on double click on selected value on the grid view.

This is done by DataGridView Event.

```
    private void dataGridView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Then you can use the DataGridViewCell.Value Property to retrieve the value stored in a particular cell.

```
MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString());
```

So the final code would look like this.

```
        private void dataGridView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString());
        }
```

NOTE change the Gridview name as you datagrid name